# Selective highlighting of cells using xml/xslt 1

Tags: xml, xslt

I will try to explain ...

I have a schedule that lists the assignments for several people. This schedule is created by using XML/XSLT.

I now want to not only just make the schedule, but replicate one copy for each person used on the schedule. Their names would be highlighted on the schedule.

I was thinking about adding a node into the XML with a list of the names used on the schedule. Then I wondered if it would be possible to enumerate this list of names and then prepare the schedule, and somehow, instead of just showing the names, I selectively wrap them in a class so that they highlight.

Does this make sense? I may have not explained it very well. I don't know how to go about it. The end product is a HTML file. My current XSL template is 855 lines long.

Comment: As the result of the XSLT transformation is HTML, you should look into applying CSS to some element(s) in the result HTML e.g. assuming you create a list of elements you would use `<li class="highlight">...</li>` and in the head of the generated HTML you would define the CSS inline (`<style>.highlight { font-weight: bold; font-size: 120% }</style>` or reference an external CSS file with e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sheet.css"/>`.

Comment: Hi Martin. I am aware of how to highlight the text using CSS and a class. The question was more directed to the XSL logic and if I had to have lots of xsl:if clauses to test if the value was to be highlighted or not. Or if there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: So you're saying make a personalized version of the schedule for each person with their name highlighted? What version of XSLT? How are you processing the XSLT (shell script, java, etc.)?

Comment: Hi Daniel. Yes, that is right. It is XSLT 1.0. The XML file is opened by Internet Explorer and it does the processing.

Comment: You could write this using a passed parameter to determine what to highlight.  If using a shell script, you could then just process it once for each person, passing in the name for the parameter.  If you are doing it by having IE open the xml, I don't see any way for IE to know who should be highlighted.  I think your best bet is to use the CSS method having each person get a custom CSS file.